# Vector gets stored as a dataframe instead of being a vector

Tags: r

I am new to r and rstudio and I need to create a vector that stores the first 100 rows of the csv file the programme reads . However , despite all my attempts my variable v1 ends up becoming a dataframe instead of an int vector . May I know what I can do to solve this? Here's my code:

```
library(readr)
library(readr)
cup_data <- read_csv("C:/Users/Asus.DESKTOP-BTB81TA/Desktop/STUDY/YEAR 2/
          YEAR 2 SEM 2/PREDICTIVE ANALYTICS(1_PA_011763)/Week 1 (Intro to PA)/
                     Practical/cup98lrn variable subset small.csv")
# Retrieve only the selected columns
cup_data_small <- cup_data[c("AGE", "RAMNTALL", "NGIFTALL", "LASTGIFT", 
                     "GENDER", "TIMELAG", "AVGGIFT", "TARGET_B", "TARGET_D")]
str(cup_data_small)
cup_data_small

#get the number of columns and rows
ncol(cup_data_small)
nrow(cup_data_small)
cat("No of column",ncol(cup_data_small),"\nNo of Row :",nrow(cup_data_small))

#cat
#Concatenate and print
#Outputs the objects, concatenating the representations. 
#cat performs much less conversion than print.

#Print the first 10 rows of cup_data_small
head(cup_data_small, n=10)

#Create a vector V1 by selecting first 100 rows of AGE 
v1 <- cup_data_small[1:100,"AGE",]
```

Here's what my environment says:
[image]

Comment: The behavior is because your object is a `tibble`, not strictly a `data.frame`. With tibbles, the default behavior is to always return a single-column frame in these instances, arguing that the base method of "sometimes returning single-columns and sometimes returning vectors" can be confusing and/or problematic. (It's a `tibble` because you used `read_csv` which is from `readr`, one of the `tidyverse` packages that prefers `tbl`s over mere `data.frame`s.) To force a vector, you can use `v1 <- cup_data_small$AGE[1:100]` or `v1 <- cup_data_small[["AGE"]][1:100]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`cup_data_small` is a tibble, a slightly modified version of a dataframe that has slightly different rules to try to avoid some common quirks/inconsistencies in standard dataframes. E.g. in a standard dataframe, `df[, c("a")]` gives you a vector, and `df[, c("a", "b")]` gives you a dataframe - you're using the same syntax so arguably they should give the same type of result.

To get just a vector from a tibble, you have to explicitly pass `drop = TRUE`, e.g.:

```
library(dplyr)

# Standard dataframe
iris[, "Species"]

iris_tibble = iris %>%
    as_tibble()
# Remains a tibble/dataframe
iris_tibble[, "Species"]
# This gives you just the vector
iris_tibble[, "Species", drop = TRUE]
```